# How to insert a date (based on a cell reference) in file Title?

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a macro that saves an Excel file to PDF, but I would like to insert the date within the saved file name based on a particular cell reference in the workbook in a "yyyy-mm-dd" date format.

The specific sheet in the workbook that I want to reference is titled "Variables and Macros"; the particular cell that contains the date is cell B4 within that sheet.

The current recorded macro is below:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "Z:\Regional Weekly Report\11 May\Forecast Template\Fiscal 2015 Weekly Projections 2015-05-24.pdf" _
```

I would ideally like to keep this section static:
`Z:\Regional Weekly Report\11 May\Forecast Template\Fiscal 2015 Weekly Projections` and add a cell reference for the date after; such as `& Text('Variables and Macros'!B4,"yyyy-mm-dd"`.  I've looked at similar posts (i.e. adding `Range("B4").Value`) but nothing seems to be working, I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try do this

<kbd>**Excel 2010**</kbd>

```
Sub SaveAs()
    Dim SavePath    As String
    Dim SaveAs      As String
    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim sDate       As String

    '// Save it Path
    SavePath = "Z:\Regional Weekly Report\11 May\Forecast Template\"

    '// File Name
    FileName = "Fiscal 2015 Weekly Projections "

    '// Format the on "B4" to YYYY-MM-DD
    sDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4"), "YYYY-MM-DD")

    '// Save with File Name & Date & .pdf
    SaveAs = FileName & sDate & ".pdf"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        '// Export Active Sheet as pdf
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
            SavePath & SaveAs

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It worked but it is saving the current date (5/29/2015) - instead of using "Now" as the date, is it possible to adjust the VBA code to point to cell B4 of a tab titled "Variables and Macros" to use whatever date is in cell B4 (ie. 5/24/2015?)

Comment: @SamRow323 never mind you don't have to format the cells i edited the code take look now

Comment: How do I accept the answer? Sorry, first time posting a question on here.